# Why Loopback stores all document change history?

Tags: javascript, strongloop

When we talk about loopback offer the "trackChanges" option that allows us to store changes made to a document. Why Loopback stores the entire history of documents instead of storing only the changed (as git does...).

- [LB Synchronization](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Synchronization)